# Prove that there exists $x \le 4^n$ such that $x \equiv i \mod p_i$ for all $1 \le i \le t$, given all prime $p_i \le n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Let $p_1, \cdots, p_t$ be all prime numbers between $2$ and $n$. Prove that there exists $x \le 4^n$ such that $x \equiv i \mod p_i$ for all $1 \le i \le t$.

My attempts:

From [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

$$x = \sum_{i=1}^t i M_i N_i \mod N$$
with $N = \prod_{j=1}^t p_j$, $N_i = \frac{N}{p_i}$ and $M_i$ is the inverse element of $N_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}^*$.

$$x \le N \le \prod_{i=1}^t p_i = e^{\sum_{i=0}^t \log p_i} \le e^{\pi(n) * \log n} \sim e^{n} \le 4^n$$

In the last $\sim$ step, I used the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). However, this is only correct when $n \rightarrow \infty$. I haven't proven in any $n$ and $t$.

Another method is that
$$x \le N \le \prod_{i=1}^t p_i = e^{\sum_{i=0}^t \log p_i} \le e^{\theta(n)} \le e^{1.000028 n} < 2.8^n < 4^n$$
with $\theta(n)$ [1st Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function), and [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Asymptotics_and_bounds) $\theta(n) < 1.000028 n$.

**However, I haven't used the property: $x = i \mod p_i$ in this problem.** Since it's only homework for undergraduate abstract algebra, I'm curious whether there is any fundamental solution without the use of the [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function)?

Comment: I would suggest you look at Chebishev's attempt to prove the prime number theorem. The sum of logarithms of primes up to $N$ is sometimes denoted $\Phi(N)$, and I think Chebishev has a uniform bound $\Phi(N) < C*N$ with an explicit $C > 1$ which may be smaller than $\log 4$.

Comment: @kindasorta I'm curious whether there is any easy solution without prime number theorem or Chebyshev function? It's a homework of undergrad algebra course.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: note that the binomial $2n\choose n$ is divisible by all primes between $n$ and $2n$ on the one hand, and is at most $(1 + 1)^{2n}$ on the other hand.

Comment: Cool result, never noticed but obvious after pointed out.  Lower bound exclusive.